# Set multiple rows and columns of large scipy sparse matrix to 0s

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to "translate" some Matlab code into Python and there is one line in Matlab that sets multiple rows in a sparse matrix to 0s:

```
Ks(idx,:)=0; %no affinity for W inside fs
```

where `Ks` is the sparse matrix (which is symmetrical and with pretty big size), and `idx` is an 1D array denoting the row indices to do the changes and it's also quite big in size. And in the next line it also changes those columns to 0s, so `Ks` is still symmetric:

```
Ks(:,idx)=0;
```

Doing the similar thing in Python (`Ks[idx,:]=0`) seems to only work for small matrices, when it gets big I got `MemoryError`. Currently my `Ks` is a csr matrix, converting it to `lil` and do that is super slow.

I'm not quite familiar with sparse matrices, I know that in Python there are more than 1 type (e.g. csr, csc, lil etc.), but in the Matlab code there aren't such distinctions, I only found a function call of `sparse()`. So what's my best bet in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed up is , instead of setting the sparse matrix elements to zero , first set the elements of numpy nd array to zero , and then convert to sparse matrix. I got a speed boost of more than 10 times in the below example.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
np.random.seed(20)
mat = np.random.randint(-2000,2000,size=(1000,1000))
sym_mat = (mat + mat.T)/2

zero_rows =  np.random.randint(0,999,(900,))


%%timeit
sparse = sps.csr_matrix(sym_mat)
sparse[zero_rows,:] = 0
sparse[:,zero_rows] = 0

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:774: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
1 loop, best of 3: 206 ms per loop

%%timeit
sym_mat[zero_rows,:] = 0
sym_mat[:,zero_rows] = 0
sparse1 = sps.csr_matrix(sym_mat)

100 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But converting the sparse to numpy ndarray will give MemoryError, I guess the size is simply too big (the case I'm testing atm is 185600x185600, and it could be larger).